# Laptop webcam works with BlueStacks but not with Nox

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, camera, noxplayer

I have an MSI laptop with an integrated webcam and I need the camera to function using Nox Player. I've read everywhere that the camera is supposed to work out of the box with Nox. However, it doesn't.

I installed BlueStacks to check and it worked with BlueStacks.
On Nox, whatever app I install, it acts as if there is no camera.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

MEMU is suspect and is "not safe" to use in my experience, and my camera has sync issues with that emulator that messes up my apps and network settings.

My understanding is the latest NOX version uses Android 7. The webcam at this time is not supported.

That's all the info I can find on this. And sadly, BlueStacks records me sideways.

Comment: For fixing the Camera sideway problem in some apps in the BlueStacks, open the BlueStacks settings, then Display and then select a portrait view or a custom resolution with the same width and height pixel.

Answer (score 0):

Install "CPU X" app on Nox, then go to "Camera" menu and back. that's all.
It may correct your problem.

Comment: 'CPU X' is nice tool but it is not a solution for this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [ManyCam](https://manycam.com/). ManyCam comes with additioanly several features. For example: It can be reflect desktop screen in camera for Qr code read process.

Answer (score -1):

So I gave [MEMU](https://www.memuplay.com/) a try, and it has all Nox features + the camera works.

MEMU is an Android emulator very similar to Nox Player. Installation is straightforward, nothing special is needed, and the camera works out of the box.